# res.redirect is coming as undefined

Tags: node.js

I have following function written in server.js I keep getting `error: uncaughtException: Cannot call method 'redirect' of undefined`

```
function(req, res) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(next){
      next(null, res);
    },

    function(next){
      next(null, res);
    },
    function(next, res){
      res.redirect('www.google.com')
    }
  ]);
}
```

After making above changes from the answer below I'm getting, error as follows:

```
2014-09-04T13:56:08.678Z - error: uncaughtException: Object function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    callback.apply(null, arguments);
                    callback = function () {};
                }
                else {
                    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
                    var next = iterator.next();
                    if (next) {
                        args.push(wrapIterator(next));
                    }
                    else {
                        args.push(callback);
                    }
                    async.nextTick(function () {
                        iterator.apply(null, args);
                    });
                }
            } has no method 'send'
```

Comment: Did you pass the `res` to the function?

Comment: i have my function written exactly like above

Comment: Did you call the anonymous function with passing the `res` from `.createServer` or else? Or is it inside of another function?

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need to pass res as waterfall parameter? You can use it from global scope of function, simply like this

```
function(req, res) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(next){
      next();
    },

    function(next){
      next();
    },
    function(){
      res.redirect('www.google.com')
    }
  ]);
}
```

Comment: In this scenario, why can't you remove `async.waterfall` completely?

Comment: Because if you need to perform task in series & proper order and pass result from one task to next one it will this will protect you from callback hell.

Comment: I meant exactly in this scenario. But I know what you mean.